# Perl, check if pair exists in hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

In Perl, I have a hash of hashes created with a loop similar to the following

```
    my %HoH
    for my $i (1..10) {
      $HoH{$a}{$b} = $i; 
    }
```

$a and $b are variables that do have some value when the HoH gets filled in. After creating the HoH, how can I check if a particular pair ($c, $d) exists in the HoH? The following does not work

```
if (defined $HoH{$c}{$d}) {...}
```

because if $c does not exist in HoH already, it will be created as a key without a value.

Comment: Not quite: If the hash doesn't contain a value for `$c` it will be created as a reference to a (new, anonymous) hash because that's how it's used. This is called "autovivification."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %HoH;

$HoH{A}{B} = 1;

if(exists $HoH{C} && exists $HoH{C}{D}) {
   print "exists\n";
}

print Dumper(\%HoH);

if(exists $HoH{C}{D}) {
   print "exists\n";
}

print Dumper(\%HoH);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'A' => {
                   'B' => 1
                 }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'A' => {
                   'B' => 1
                 },
          'C' => {}
        };
```

Autovivification is causing the keys to be created.  "exists" in my second example shows this so the first example checks both keys individually.

Comment: You don’t really have to use the cumbersome `exists`, you know.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why the first example works as it should while the second does not?

Answer (score 4):

Writing

```
if (defined $HoH{$c}{$d}) {...}
```

will "work" insomuch as it will tell you whether or not `$HoH{$c}{$d}` has a defined value. The problem is that if `$HoH{$c}` doesn't already exist it will be created (with an appropriate value) so that `$HoH{$c}{$d}` can be tested. This process is called "autovivification." It's convenient when setting values, e.g.

```
my %hoh;
$hoh{a}{b} = 1; # Don't need to set '$hoh{a} = {}' first
```

but inconvenient when retrieving possibly non-existent values. I wish that Perl was smart enough to only perform autovivification for expressions used as lvalues and short-circuit to return `undef` for rvalues but, alas, it's not that magical. The [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) pragma (available on CPAN) adds the functionality to do this.

To avoid autovivification you need to test the intermediate values first:

```
if (exists $HoH{$c} && defined $HoH{$c}{$d}) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: @tchrist: I think it more clearly expresses the intent of "is there something there?" Without the `exists` it looks like a test for Boolean truth. References are true of course, so it works and it's more concise, but it isn't really the truthiness of the value that we care about. As a side benefit, it's slightly faster to check for existence than to retrieve the value.

Comment: Perhaps. I suspect you and I simply think of these things in different ways. In my model, the `exists`, being redundant, draws especial attention to itself and makes me ponder whether there isn’t something sneaky afoot. I have the same reaction when I see someone write `"$var"` when `$var` would do. That said, I myself consistently write `$count = scalar(@array)`, even though the `scalar` is superfluous. I think we wish to remind ourselves and others of our indent, but that what “needs” reminding may vary between writer and reader.

Comment: You have to be careful about leaving off the `exists`, if you're truly testing for existence.  If you want to know whether `bar` exists in `%foo`, and you just do `if $foo{bar}` and `$foo{bar} == 0`, you may not get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:

```
if ( $HoH{$c} && defined $HoH{$c}{$d} ) {...}
```

or

```
if ( defined ${ $HoH{$c} || {} }{$d} ) {...}
```

or

```
no autovivification;
if (defined $HoH{$c}{$d}) {...}
```

or

```
use Data::Diver;
if ( defined Data::Diver::Dive( \%HoH, $c, $d ) ) {...}
```

Comment: I find the second option offensive to my delicate sensibilities. (i.e. it's an interesting trick, but please don't use it.)

Comment: What’s with all the `defined` business?

Comment: @Michael Carman: it's an idiom.  I worked on a codebase where it was ubiquitous and once I adapted it no longer offended me.  I suspect the same is true of most idioms: they are best used widely or not at all.

Comment: @tchrist: that's what the OP was checking.  might not be what he wants, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) function

> exists EXPR
>
> Given an expression that specifies an
>   element of a hash, returns true if the
>   specified element in the hash has ever
>   been initialized, even if the
>   corresponding value is undefined.
>
> Note that the EXPR can be arbitrarily
>   complicated as long as the final
>   operation is a hash or array key
>   lookup or subroutine name:
>
> 1. if (exists $ref->{A}->{B}->{$key}) { }
> 2. if (exists $hash{A}{B}{$key}) { }

Comment: Doesn't work, I think because I am not trying to see whether a $key exists, but whether $hash{A}{B} is defined... Thanks anyway!

Comment: `exists` doesn't subvert autovivification.

Comment: `exists` is neither a necessary nor a sufficient measure to effect the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
use List::Util   qw<first>;
use Params::Util qw<_HASH>;

sub exists_deep (\[%$]@) {
    my $ref = shift;
    return unless my $h = _HASH( $ref ) // _HASH( $$ref )
              and defined( my $last_key = pop )
              ;
    # Note that this *must* be a hash ref, for anything else to make sense.
    return if first { !( $h = _HASH( $h->{ $_ } )) } @_;
    return exists $h->{ $last_key };
}
```

You could also do this recursively. You could also create a descent structure allowing intermediate and even terminal arrayref with just a little additional coding.